# ClipDrawable getDrawable() returns a StateListDrawable

Tags: java, android

I need to access a [`ClipDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html) to set the clip level.  Here is the drawable:

`@drawable/left_arrow`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <clip
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:drawable="@drawable/rotated_square"
      android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
      android:gravity="left" />
  </item>
</selector>
```

`@drawable/rotated_square`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <rotate
      android:fromDegrees="45"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:toDegrees="45">
      <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
          android:width="250dp"
          android:height="250dp"/>
        <solid
          android:color="#ffffff"/>
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</selector>
```

When I try to retrieve the drawable `left_arrow` as a [`ClipDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html) like this:

```java
ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.left_arrow);
```

I get the following error in LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable
        at com.vcapra1.pingpongscoreboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:89)
```

Why is my [`ClipDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html) being returned as a StateListDrawable?

Comment: it is indeed a statelistdrawable whose first element is "your drawable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `left_arrow` is a `StateListDrawable` because it has a `<selector>` as its root element. If you want to have it as a `ClipDrawable` you should use the `<clip>` element directly as the XML's root without the `<selector>` and `<item>` tags.